# Spring HttpMessageConverter for only one Controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm aware of and comfortable with using Spring message converters to automatically convert the objects that a Controller returns into, e.g. JSON. However, I haven't been able to find any information about applying a particular message converter to *only one* of the several Controllers in the app.

Basically, I have one particular piece of the app that will show audit log entries, and will only ever be viewed by the admin, so it doesn't need to be pretty. I'd like to write a quick HttpMessageConverter that takes a `List<AuditEntry>` and returns a string with an HTML table of the entries, but everything else in the app is user-facing and gets sent over as JSON. Is this possible? I didn't see any mention of it in the docs I read. If it is, what's the magic XML?

Answer (score -1):

The `@RequestMapping` anotation has `produce`

> produces
>   The producible media types of the mapped request, narrowing the primary mapping.

so in the case of JSON you have in the `produce` - "application\json"

when you want to return html you can use "text\html" and use the `ModelAndView` of [Spring-MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)